# Django using self on __init__ when not saved in database

Tags: python, django, reference, initialization

Is it possible to use self as a reference in the `__init__` method when the object is not instantiated yet?

What I'm trying to do is :

```
class MyClass(models.Model)
    __init__(self):
        some_attributes = AnotherClass.objects.filter(foreignkey=self)
```

The thing is that as the instance of MyClass is not registered in db yet, I have an exception like "MyClass has not attribute id"

I tried to add

```
if self.pk:
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a method like

```
if self.is_saved_in_db(): 
     #some code
```

or do I have to created this one ?

**EDIT**

To be more specific, I'll give an example. I have a generic class which I try to hydrate with attributes from another Model.

```
class MyClass(models.Model)
    _init__(self):
        self.hydrate()

    def hydrate(self):
        # Retrieving the related objects
    attributes = Information.objects.filter(...)
    for attr in attributes:
        attribute_id = attr.name.lower().replace(" ","_")
        setattr(self,attribute_id,attr)
```

By doing so, I can access to attributes with MyClass.my_attribute.

For a small example, if we replace MyClass by Recipe and Information with Ingredients I can do :

```
pasta_recipe.pasta
pasta_recipie.tomato
pasta_recipie.onions
```

It's a simple parsing from a foreign_key to an attribute

By writing it, I realise that it's a bit useless because I can directly use ForeignKey relationships. I think I'll do that but for my own culture, is it possible do the filter with self as attribute before database saving ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `self` before saving (for example to populate a `slug` field starting from the current value of another field), but cannot access related foreign keys to self because, well, they're not related yet as you don't have any `pk`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange thing to do. I strongly recommend you do not try to do it.

(That said, the `self.pk` check is the correct one: you need to provide more details than "it doesn't work".)

Comment: I gave more details in my original post :)

Comment: As I said, 'self.pk' is the way to do this if you must. You obviously can't filter on self before saving though, that doesn't even make sense: what would the database be querying on?